# What do we call a person who does branding?

Tags: single-word-requests

**Can you fill in the gap?**

- A person who manages a project is called a project manager.
- A person who develops the software for a project is called a developer.
- A person who designs the graphics for project is called a designer.
- A person who provides the writing for a project is called a copywriter.
- *A person who does the branding for a project is called a **________er** ???*

Comment: I would call him a *cowpoke*.

Answer (score 3):

The person who does the branding for a project is called a [brand manager](https://www.google.de/search?q="brand+manager").